# Reflection with property decorator in typescript doesn't works

Tags: angular, typescript, angularjs-decorator

I'm trying to create a decorator (NonExportable) to tell which fields in a class should not be exported. Decorator definition:

**nonexportable-decorators.ts**

```
const NON_EXPORTABLE_KEY = Symbol("NonExportable");

export default function NonExportable() {
   return Reflect.metadata(NON_EXPORTABLE_KEY, true);
}

export function isNonExportable (target: any, propertyKey: string): boolean {
   return Reflect.getMetadata(NON_EXPORTABLE_KEY, target, propertyKey);
}
```

The decorator is being used in the model "personaFisica":

**pessoaFisica.ts**

```
import NonExportable from "../nonexportable-decorator"

export class Contribuinte {
    ni: string; 
    @NonExportable()    
    cpf: number;
    @NonExportable()    
    cnpjEstabelecimento: number;
}
```

However, apparently nothing is being written to the metadata, since a **undefined** value is returned when executing the **Reflect.isNonExportable** function.**isNonExportable** always return false. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How are you using `isNonExportable`?

Comment: I use to select which properties will be exported to CSV file.

`let objCols: string[] = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(objContribuinte);
objCols.forEach(col => {
   if (!isNonExportable(listObjs[0], col)) {
      strCsv += col;
   }
}`